# Consequences of not closing byte streams

Tags: java, stream, byte

The question says it all.
**What are the consequences of not closing the various byte streams?**

It is very much emphasized to always do so, but there is no mention of how it causes problems.
Can someone please explain what actually happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "a byte stream"? For a `ByteArrayInputStream`, there's not much impact. For a `FileInputStream` or one from a socket, that's a different matter.

Comment: I was actually asking in general. I came across this question when I was referring the docs: [Byte Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html)

Comment: Well there's no correct answer *in general*, because it depends on the specific kind of stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not only byte streams. This concerns anything implementing [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

As the documentation states:

> The close method is invoked to release resources that the object is holding (such as open files).

Whether a `Closeable` holds system resources or not, the rule of thumb is: **do not take the chance**. `.close()` it correctly, and you'll be ensured that such system resources (if any) are freed.

Typical idiom (note that `InputStream` implements `Closeable`):

```
final InputStream in = whateverIsNeeded;
try {
    workWith(in);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

With Java 7 you also have `AutoCloseable` (which `Closeable` implements) and the try-with-resources statement, so do:

```
try (
    final InputStream in = whateverIsNeeded;
) {
    workWith(in);
}
```

This will handle closing `in` for you.

Again: don't take the chance. And if you don't use JDK 7 but can afford Guava, use [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html).

Answer (score 2):

Not closing *limited* resources such as database connections will dramatically slow down execution, and likely result in errors as those connections run out, with old ones sitting there unused.

Not closing file-streams could result in multiple threads writing to the same file, or files not being terminated properly, or files being locked when another thread attempts to write or read it.

This is a major topic relating to all `Closeable`s, as stated by @fge. There are numerous libraries supplying things such as [connection pools](https://www.google.com/search?q=connection%20pool%20library%20java) and [caches](http://ehcache.org/) for handling problems such as this.

More information:

https://www.google.com/search?q=consequentes+of+not+closing+resources+java

Answer (score 0):

It will hang around util collected by the GC. (thus holding to unmanaged resources (files, sockets etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are several streams including:

- ByteArray
- File
- Filter
- Object
- Piped
- Corba version of the outputStream

Depending on the kind of resource is behind the stream the result could be different. In[ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#close%28%29) and [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close%28%29) where the documentation says:

> Closing a ByteArrayInputStream has no effect. The methods in this
>   class can be called after the stream has been closed without
>   generating an IOException.

But in [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29) there is an open file. If you keept it open there is memory reserved and anybody who tries to edit the file will find it locked. In case of doubt always call the close() method.